# How to adjust \listing package width in Latex Editor (LEd)

Tags: c++, latex, width

I am trying to use the \listing package to include some .cpp files into my article.

I add:

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

And then I use `\lstinputlisting[language=c++]{File.cpp}`

The problem is that the width is not adjusted, so the code is cutted.

Which is the solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll be looking for the setting `breaklines` set in `\lstset` like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
\lstinputlisting[language=c++]{File.cpp}
\end{document}
```

Now `listings` will try and break the lines neatly.

For more information about what can be set with `\lstset`, see the article on [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings).